# How to add a wordpress post title to url?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to add a post title to the url, each word separated by a dash "-"

example: https://example.com/url.php?s=

add title: https://example.com/url.php?s=Hello-World

(Sample title of the post: "Hello World!")

Is it possible? Can someone do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**addition:**
base on your clarification in the comment. you can try using sanitize_title().
something like this:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/?s='.sanitize_title(get_the_title());
echo $url
```

---

using the parameter "s" is not possible because this is the parameter for search in wordpress.
do need it to be a parameter? because wordpress comes with permalink options that can dd the post title to the url like this:
https://example.com/this-is-the-post-title

if this suits you, then log in to the admin area, go to "settings" -> "permalinks" and there you can choose the url format you'll like.

Comment: I mean a completely different url, not wordpress. I want the script to automatically add to url, title from wp post which is currently in

Comment: added a possible solution  to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I mean :)